# Get results with all values after decimal in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a dataframe where the time values are something like 8.000024 due to high sampling rate. When I extract these values from DF, the series shows the time values as 8.0 and I would like to have the full values. How do I do this ? My code is as below:

```
x = str(input('Enter file name with extension: ')) 
df = pd.read_csv(x, delimiter=";", dtype=float, na_values=["-∞", "∞"],)  # loads the csv files

time = df['Time'].astype('float')
time.round(6)
print(time)
```

Comment: So looks like the conversion from ASCII file to CSV was the problem. I can see all the decimal values in the ASCII file but not in the CSV file. I opened it in Notepad and saved as a CSV file. Does anyone know how this could be solved ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and the output is

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Time": [
        6.001234154,
        7.000124131,
        8.000024465,
        9.00000112234,
        10.00000023254,
        11.000000012410149,
    ]
})

time = df['Time'].astype('float')
time.round(6)
print(time)
```

Make sure the data is correct in your sourcefiles.
Can't say more since your example isn't reproducible.

If you still have issues, please give a snippet/export from your sourcefile.

```
0     6.001234
1     7.000124
2     8.000024
3     9.000001
4    10.000000
5    11.000000
Name: Time, dtype: float64
```

## Edit

The [sourcefile](https://seafile.zfn.uni-bremen.de/f/9911eae2ba0c482798ff/?dl=1) was linked.
And the file's first line is
`8.00E+00;3.09E-03;1.97E-03;3.41E-03;3.66E-03;3.88E-03;2.44E-03`

So resaving your ascii as csv must have rounded the numbers to 2 significant digits.

Comment: My source file was an ascii that I re-saved as a CSV and also deleted a few rows. Could that be a reason ?

Comment: File link is [here](https://seafile.zfn.uni-bremen.de/f/9911eae2ba0c482798ff/?dl=1)!:

Comment: Would you have an idea how this rounding could be increased to 6 digits ?

Comment: You should ask a separate about that step / check what you do there

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I could directly import the .asd file using pd.read_csv

```
x = 'filename'
df = pd.read_csv(x, skiprows=12, delimiter=";", dtype=float, na_values=["-∞", "∞"])
```